# Как получить самое маленькое значение из ArrayList в Java?

Tags: java, массивы, arraylist

У меня есть список "ArrayList" из ста элементов "distances". 
Я хочу проитись по каждой десятке из них и выбрать самое маленькое значение. На пример:

```
ArrayList
    {10,21,12,23,34,5,61,72,18,9}   // min value = 5
    {21,36,12,45,85,45,6,89,53,11}  // min value = 6
    {1,23,22,11,3,44,54,44,1,2,33}  // min value = 1 ...и так до конца списка
```

Это должно быть методом, который возвращает по одному этому значению за раз, а не как целый список из этих маленьких значеий.

Вот что у меня пока -

```
// 100 elements of distances
private List<Double> xAndY;

//constructor
public Distance(List<Double> xAndY) {
    this.xAndY = xAndY;
}

public double distances(Distance distance) {
    //shortest distance
    double minValue = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < this.xAndY.size(); i++) {
        if (this.xAndY.size() < 10) {
            minValue = getMin(distance.getXandY().subList(0, 9));
        }
        if (this.xAndY.size() > 10 && this.xAndY.size() < 20) {
            minValue = getMin(distance.getXandY().subList(10, 19));
        }
        if (this.xAndY.size() > 20 && this.xAndY.size() < 30) {
            minValue = getMin(distance.getXandY().subList(20, 29));
        }
        if (this.xAndY.size() > 30 && this.xAndY.size() < 40) {
            minValue = getMin(distance.getXandY().subList(30, 39));
        }
        if (this.xAndY.size() > 40 && this.xAndY.size() < 50) {
            minValue = getMin(distance.getXandY().subList(40, 49));
        }
        if (this.xAndY.size() > 50 && this.xAndY.size() < 60) {
            minValue = getMin(distance.getXandY().subList(50, 59));
        }
        if (this.xAndY.size() > 60 && this.xAndY.size() < 70) {
            minValue = getMin(distance.getXandY().subList(60, 69));
        }
        if (this.xAndY.size() > 70 && this.xAndY.size() < 80) {
            minValue = getMin(distance.getXandY().subList(70, 79));
        }
        if (this.xAndY.size() > 80 && this.xAndY.size() < 90) {
            minValue = getMin(distance.getXandY().subList(80, 89));
        }
        if (this.xAndY.size() > 90 && this.xAndY.size() < 100) {
            minValue = getMin(distance.getXandY().subList(90, 99));
        }
    }
    return minValue;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Double getMin(ArrayList<Double> list) {
    return Collections.min(list);
}
```

создаем цикл заполняющий doublesMin с десятью минимальными значениями из каждой десятки

```
// тут будут 10 знач из каждой десятки
ArrayList<Double> doublesMin = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    doublesMin.add(getMin(doubleArrayList.subList(10 * i, i * 10 + 9)));
}
```

Comment: Я вот добавил этот код, но возвращает 0 везде. Или как-то не так прошелся по списку. Я кстати добавил код в свой вопрос. Можете посмотреть.

Comment: @Marin вам нужно 10 значений вы получаете одно, впрочем из последней десятки, я добавил цикл в ответ

Comment: Это вроде как возвращает список если я верно понимаю? Мне бы как-то только одно значение за итерацию

Comment: @Marin уберите ваши if и вызывайте getMin(distance.getXandY().subList(n, n+9)) - 10 раз с разными minValue1, minValue2, ..., minValue10

Comment: Каждый раз новую переменую заполнять? Но как тогда, из метода выходить? Мне нужен return, а тут вроде как void метод получается, верно я понимаю?

Answer (score 1):

**На стримах:** Берем массив из 10 элементов, открываем по нему `stream`, сортируем по возрастанию (natural order), берем из него первый элемент, и, если он есть (т.е. массив был не пустой), тогда выводим результат в консоль.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Integer[] arr1 = new Integer[] {10, 21, 12, 23, 34, 5, 61, 72, 18, 9};
    Integer[] arr2 = new Integer[] {21, 36, 12, 45, 85, 45, 6, 89, 53, 11};
    Integer[] arr3 = new Integer[] {1, 23, 22, 11, 3, 44, 54, 44, 1, 2, 33};

    soutArr(arr1); // 5
    soutArr(arr2); // 6
    soutArr(arr3); // 1
}

private static void soutArr(Integer[] arr) {
    Stream.of(arr).sorted().findFirst().ifPresent(System.out::println);
}
```

То же самое с листом:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();

    // Заполняем лист как-то.. Например:
    list.addAll(Arrays.asList(arr1));
    list.addAll(Arrays.asList(arr2));
    list.addAll(Arrays.asList(arr3));

    soutList(list.subList(0, 9));   // 5
    soutList(list.subList(10, 19)); // 6
    soutList(list.subList(20, 29)); // 1
}

private static void soutList(List<Integer> list) {
    list.stream().sorted().findFirst().ifPresent(System.out::println);
}
```

Comment: Я разробатываю на андроиде 6.0.0 так что стримы не работают еще. Можно ли как-нибудь менее современым способ?